::operator new overload does not work anymore?
C++ always declared the possibility to redefine global memory allocator, redefining ::operator new and ::operator delete in global scope. Example operator_new has code for int. This design considered, that program consists of many OBJ files, and linker includes our version of ::operator new to the final executable.
Currently linux and MacOSX c++ libraries are dynamic (MSVC++ also tends to build only DLL versions of the programs). I faced the situation, that my overloaded operator located in main program dynamic segment, but class constructor code (f.e. std::string) is in libc++ dynamic library segment, and constructor never call my overloaded operator, it is already bind to standard version of operator new in the library
// never call overloaded ::operator new, 
// constructor is compiled and linked to stdc++ and call version from stdc++ library.
std::string str="012345678901234567890123456789";

. A library, called by parent library, is not call functions from the parent library, if it has the function with the same name. It calls only own library functions or functions from daughter libraries.
Is there some way to force dynamic library loader to bind function from parent library instead of own library function? Otherwise C++ loses functionality, that is declared as language feature, but actually does not work in modern operating systems.
P.S. My program needs own memory allocator, but it depends on big volume of C++ code. C++ code constructors defined in my executable and in STL header files use overloaded operator new. Problem with constructors defined and compiled into std c++ library - most of the usefull standard classes.
P.S.S I tried to define operator new as weak_import, but it does not affect calling priority.
P.S.S.S Minimal reproducable example:
-----
CMakeLists.txt
-----
# mkdir build
# cd build
# cmake ..
# make
# ./str
# output is: 123456789012345678901234567890
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(Dynlibs)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
add_executable(str str.cpp)
add_library(res SHARED res.cpp)
target_link_libraries(str res)
set_property(TARGET str PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET str PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set_property(TARGET str PROPERTY CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

----
res.cpp
----
#include <string>
std::string res();

std::string res()
{
    const char *tst="123456789012345678901234567890";
    return tst;
}
-----
str.cpp
-----

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>


// no inline, required by [replacement.functions]/3
void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
    std::printf("1) new(size_t), size = %zu\n", sz);
    if (sz == 0)
        ++sz; // avoid std::malloc(0) which may return nullptr on success

    if (void *ptr = std::malloc(sz))
        return ptr;

    throw std::bad_alloc{}; // required by [new.delete.single]/3
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::puts("3) delete(void*)");
    std::free(ptr);
}

extern std::string res();

int main()
{
    std::string str=res();
    std::puts( str.c_str() );
}



variable str allocated by default operator new without message. If I move res() to str.cpp, operator will be overloaded.
P.S.S.
I tested it on MacOsX 12.5.1 , overload does not work:
compiler Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
library in MacOsX SDK 13.1 
output of nm -V ...path to libc++
Apple LLVM version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  Optimized build.
  Default target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
  Host CPU: apple-a12
llvm-nm, compatible with GNU nm

I tested it on Linux and overload works:
OS (SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux) 
compiler c++ (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0
Library I suppose libstdc++

I tested on Windows, new is not overloaded, delete overloaded (it is normal, it called locally)
MSWindows 10, MSVC++ 2022 , SDK 10.0.22000.0

At least clang or MacOsX does not guarantie this overload.

std::string uses a special allocator structure, which may or may not use operator new. It might use operator new[]?

And the best way to handle string allocations is to create your own allocator structure, not overload the global operators.

30 characters might not be long enough for std::string to have to dynamically allocate memory due to small string optimisations

@Someprogrammerdude std::allocator is guaranteed to use the global operator new/operator delete to allocate memory. That shouldn't be the problem.

std::string, if it performs an allocation to store its elements (i.e. no SSO), is guaranteed to use your global operator new/operator delete replacements. All of this should be considered correctly by the standard library implementation and there shouldn't be any problem caused by linking. The standard library implementations of operator new and operator delete will be marked for the linker in such a way that your replacement will always be preferred, no matter how it is linked. If std::string isn't using your replacements, then please show a [mre] demonstrating it.

Wait you are expecting that dynamic library will be impacted by overloaded new operator defined in main program which loads this library?

@MarekR It ought to behave that way automatically.

@MarekR Yes, it ought to behave this way, but it does not behave. Looks like C++ promises it, but operating system in modern configuration effectively prevent it.

@Vladlen C++ do not promise that. C++ standard doesn't define behavior of libraries.

@user17732522 I provided minimal working example. I expected, that operator new marked some way, but I do not see it in linking result, not see any difference of operator , if look at library by "nm libstdc++.dylib"

@MarekR ::operator new(unsigned long) is exception case in C++, that does not require any header file and declarations. I expect, it is mentioned in some way in the standard, but I did not looked it frankly speaking.

@Vladlen Please also add the compiler and standard library implementation you are using (with versions) and the OS on which you are testing (that isn't clear to me from your current question).

@user17732522 I added OS and compiler version. At least on Linux this example works, but I can try other variations to check.

@Vladlen Unfortunately I do not have an Apple system to test this. Someone else might be able to reproduce it.

@user17732522 I changed CMakeFiles.txt for Windows. In Windows overload also does not work. Here cmake generate project files for MSVC++

@Vladlen I know that Windows is weird with allocation in DLLs. I wouldn't be surprised if it had special rules regarding operator new replacements. But I don't use Windows either, so I can't help with that. Linux/GCC seems to behave for you as I would expect it to behave everywhere.

@user17732522 You comment, that operator new marked in library,  is correct. I found, that MacOsX Intel has this mark (weak) and overload works, but MacOsX M1 library does not have mark weak, and overload does not work.
